# The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST

Tags: php, laravel

I'm following a tutorial of Laravel, but I've an error:

> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

The code of web.php is this:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/p/create', 'PostsController@create');
Route::post('/p', 'PostsController@store');

Route::get('/profile/{user}', 'ProfilesController@index')->name('profile.show');
```

and the code of create.blade.php is this:

```
<form action="/p" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
        @csrf
...
```

The code of PostsController.php

```
public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function create(){
        return view('posts.create');
    }

    public function store(){
        $data = request()->validate([
            'caption' => 'required',
            'image' => ['required', 'image'],
        ]);

        auth()->user()->posts()->create($data);

        dd(request()->all());
    }
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: On which line is the error occurring?  Clearly, you are attempting to `GET` from a page that doesn't support it.  Figure out which it is, which is _possibly_ `/p/create` judging from your code.

Comment: I hope you aren't doing any redirect back in your code after form post.

Comment: It's most likely that you are trying to return a view from the `store` method in `PostController`. But you can't return a view from a `post` route.

Comment: Instead redirect to a `get` route after the form is processed, and return the view from that route.

Comment: I updated the post with the code of PostsController.php. @Martin i don't know on which line is the error occurring, I have only that error and no more explanations.

Comment: @k32y You *can* return a view for a POST. It's not a [best practice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get), but it's certainly *possible*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, the error was trivial...
I made a mistake in the address... I've written "localhost:8000/p" instead of the correct address "localhost:8000/p/create".
Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `action="<form action="{{url('/p')}}" method="POST">`

Answer (score -1):

can you include the line of the error?

we'll assume u get the error in your post so u can try this below;

You can name your route like this;

```
Route::post('/p', 'PostsController@store')->name('post.post');
```

and use it in your route builder like this

```
<form action="{{ route('post.post') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
```